# HP Fortify Cross Site Scripting Issue on File BinaryWrite

Tags: c#, xss

I have the below code when scanned through HP Fortify, showed XSS issue on the following line : Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

What can I do to fix the XSS issue pointed out by Fortify?

```
    void ShowPDF(string infilepath)
    {
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Byte[] buffer = client.DownloadData(infilepath);

        Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", buffer.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition","attachment; filename=hearingprep.pdf");
        Response.BinaryWrite(buffer);

    }
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Raised the issue as false positive, with ensuring the incoming file locations as trusted location.

Answer (score -1):

What Fortify said is that you put ***untrusted*** content to the browser.

When you do `BinaryWrite(buffer)`. The rule triggered from Fortify is probably because you use directly the `buffer` coming from `DownloadData` (who come from a untrusted source ).

1. So First, try to add a sanitizing capability to your code on the string `infilepath`and see what's happen.
2. After that, if you can add sanitizing to the `Byte[] buffer`, this should definitively solve the vulns spot by Fortify.

If you can not do the 2., you should be prepare to have really a XSS.

Comment: How can I sanitize the Byte[]  buffer?

Comment: That the main issue :)